# deeplink not working for google hosted url

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deep-linking

i was trying to use deep link in my flutter app . I added it in my android manifest .It worked for the fllutterbooksample.com . but when i changed it to my url which is hosted on google gcm . it didn't worked .
here is my android manifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="groove-338604.wn.r.appspot.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

here is my hosted url https://groove-338604.wn.r.appspot.com .
I want to use deeplink for my app because i am using Spotify web authentication and in that i have provided the redirected URL https://groove-338604.wn.r.appspot.com/app/v1/spotifyCallback
.So what i want is when i call my login link, which after logging in the User. call's this URL .so when that happens i want to open my app through that callback URL and parse the code which i get in the redirected URL.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for verifying your app's association with your domain? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations. See particularly the section on declaring the association: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#web-assoc

Comment: autoverify is true . its working for google app .but not for chrome . in chrome it just opens up the url

Comment: You still need to host the assetlinks.json file on your server, otherwise android doesn't know if your app is truly associated with your domain - The file should be found at https://groove-338604.wn.r.appspot.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: ok . and after it opens the app how do get the code from the URL ?

Comment: There are a few ways - if you want to avoid dependencies, you would handle the path in `MaterialApp.onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings)`. There are a few answers here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081448/flutter-deep-linking